# Firebird FreeAdHoc UDF not working after restore on another server

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1

I'm encountering a weird problem after I restored Firebird database. Production database (Firebird 2.1) runs on 64bit server and we're using FreeAdHoc library with extra functions. I've backed up production database with gbak, moved to local machine (64bit Ubuntu 13.10). I installed Firebird 2.1.5 locally and downloaded the latest FreeAdHoc library.

Now, when I try to execute some function from it via iSQL:

```
/opt/firebird/bin/isql db.fdb -user sysdba -password masterkey -i /opt/firebird/bin/command.sql
```

and the content of command.sql is

```
select f_addday(current_timestamp,10) from rdb$database;
```

it runs properly and executes that UDF function.

However, when I try to execute the same command via FlameRobin or PHP script, I get this error:

```
Engine Code    : 335544343
Engine Message :
invalid request BLR at offset 59
function F_ADDDAY is not defined
module name or entrypoint could not be found
```

Can someone advise? I think that the fact that isql executes and FlameRobin/PHP doesn't is a good lead but I lack an experience to figure out why it could be the case.

Comment: When you run isql without specifying a hostname, it will connect directly to the database, not through the server. Check what happens if you use `localhost:<path-to-db.fdb>`.

Comment: You're correct, that gave me the same error. Now why is it that UDF work locally but not via server?

Comment: Could be the server config restricts the allowed UDF locations, and therefor doesn't load the UDF.

Comment: Nope, it's 'Restrict UDF' - default. The UDF library is in correct place

Comment: Ok, it's all fixed. The reason was the fact FreeAdhocUDF.so was missing libicudataFAU.so.44, libicui18nFAU.so.44
The solution is to get the official .tar.gz with FreeAdHoc UDF and run script from /install/UDF_Linux/icu/64bit/

Comment: Good to hear, but weird that it worked with an isql direct connection...

Comment: I know why - direct and server access had each different config files! Direct had UDF location correctly, but server's firebird.conf had it wrong